# Java 11: OSGi: Spawning EntityManager, Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, osgi, apache-karaf

I am in the middle of converting a Java 8 project to Java 11, and as a part of that conversion I have made a slew of different code changes and upgrades (most notably upgrading to Hibernate 5.3.18.FINAL from 4.X).  I've gotten the entire, large project to compile successfully in Java 11.  However, when I kick off the project using Karaf, I am getting a persistent OSGi error, and it's driving me crazy.

```
    [FelixDispatchQueue] ERROR org.osgi.framework.FrameworkEvent - FrameworkEvent ERROR
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: abc] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1327) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1253) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:96) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.createAndPublishEMF(AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:371) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.dataSourceReady(AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:538) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.foundDS(AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:510) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.DataSourceTracker.addingService(DataSourceTracker.java:86) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.DataSourceTracker.addingService(DataSourceTracker.java:34) ~[?:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.<init>(AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:99) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceProviderTracker.addingService(PersistenceProviderTracker.java:88) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceProviderTracker.addingService(PersistenceProviderTracker.java:44) ~[?:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.trackProvider(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:229) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.findPersistenceUnits(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:213) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.addingBundle(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:98) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.addingBundle(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:44) ~[?:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:415) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444) ~[osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:915) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:516) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4579) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2231) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2146) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.BundleInstallSupportImpl.startBundle(BundleInstallSupportImpl.java:165) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1154) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:1044) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1063) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2131) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:962) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup$Dispatcher$ForJava9CapableVm.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:1685) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.injectRaw(ClassInjector.java:1418) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$AbstractBase.inject(ClassInjector.java:112) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$UsingLookup.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:466) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:100) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:5662) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(ByteBuddyState.java:187) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(ByteBuddyState.java:107) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(ByteBuddyProxyHelper.java:54) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:155) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:51) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor59.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:413) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:557) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor58.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250) ~[?:?]
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy
```

Before you ask, I've put every single combination of matching bytebuddy and javassist in the pom files (matching the version required by 5.3.18.FINAL) and it doesn't fix the issue. Note that my project is building successfully in Maven but simply won't find HibernateProxy when I kick it off using karaf.  Downgrading to Java 8 is not an option - this needs to run in Java 11.

More tech details:
Using Spring Boot
Using Blueprint
Hibernate.xml is updated to persistence_2_1.xsd

```
<jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=abc)</jta-data-source>
```

Database is h2

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a perfect solution, the way I was able to temporarily get around this issue was to force the hibernate-core jar in the main classpath.  I'm sure the main issue is that hibernate-core is not in the right place, but I'm unclear as to how.  I did a lot of manipulations of poms and adding exceptions to maven-bundle-plugin, but that didn't work - only putting hibernate-core in the main classpath.